# What is wrong with definition of this method? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I suppose this is easy a simple question but not for me. I’m in a loop and i can not see the answer.

I try to access a method inside an object but I get this message:

```
-[SKSpriteNode playWordSound]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd75e52a60
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKSpriteNode playWordSound]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd75e52a60' ***
```

My code looks like:

Word.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Word : SKSpriteNode

- (instancetype)init;
- (void)playWordSound;

@end
```

Word.m

```
#import "Word.h"

@implementation Word 

- (instancetype)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    [self createWord];
    // some physics here
}
return self;
}

// Crear la ball con el word
- (void)createWord {

// some code here
}

- (void)playWordSound {
// some code to play a sound
}
```

And the code to call in MyScene is:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  // …
  if (other.categoryBitMask & PCWordCategory) {
        Word *wordEffect = (Word *)other.node;
        [self flyAwayWord:wordEffect];
        // HERE IS THE ERROR —
        [wordEffect playWordSound];
        // HERE IS THE ERROR -
        wordEffect.physicsBody = nil;
   }
  // …
```

}

What is wrong with definition of this method. Sorry but I can not see some obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cast wrong type:

```
Word *wordEffect = (Word *)other.node;
```

You think it is Word but actually it is

```
SKSpriteNode
```

Comment: Indeed. Casting an object to a given type doesn't morph it into that type. It just tells the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing." The error is telling you that your object is a generic SKSpriteNode object, not your custom Word class. You didn't post the code that created it, though, so we can't tell how that happened.

Comment: Thanks both for your help. Both comments help me a lot to found the solution. @DuncanC is an honor receive your comment (really). "walk_alone" I will select your answer, because give me great orientation. I'm just need add other.node.parent to access the right node.